# Asp Net 1.1 - HTMLSelect.Value not Working for Dynamically Filled Dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a form with multiple select dropdowns which are defined like this:

```
<SELECT runat=server id="select_plan_x" onchange=ChangePrice(this,x);SetSelectedText(x); name=select_plan_x> 
                                                                    <OPTION value=-1>Order by...</OPTION>
                                                                </SELECT>
```

Each of these dropdowns are dynamically filled, upon page load, with values extracted from a csv file which is called through an AJAX "GET" call. The option tag appending is done through a Javascript function.

In the code behind, i have a function which gets the inserted values in the fields to be sent to the database. When i try to use the "HTMLSelect.Value" property to fetch the selected value, it always returns the default value in the dropdown markup (the option where it says "Order by..."). However, if i use "Request.Form["select_plan_x"]", it gets the proper selected value as it should. I would like to know why the "HTMLSelect.Value" property doesn't work in this situation. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Javascript function added. This function is used to append the values from the csv into the dropdown.

```
function ChangePlan(n, control) {

                family = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).split('=')[1];
                $('#select_plan_'+n).find('option').remove().end();
                for (var i = 1; i < data.length-1; i++) {
                    var aux = data[i].split(';');
                    if (aux[0] == family) {
                        var html='<option value="'+aux[control]+'">'+ aux[1] +'</option>';
                        $('#select_plan_'+n).append(html);
                    }
                }
                ChangePrice($('#select_plan_'+n), n);
            }
```

Comment: Isn't it about time to upgrade? Version 1.1 was replaced by 2.0 in 2005. Had to look it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Versions

Comment: can you add your mark up and code behind?

Comment: I guess your html is not added to the DOM.

Comment: How can i assure that the HTML is added to the DOM?